# Populating dictionary using ArcPy creates only 1 entry?

Tags: arcpy, dictionary

I am new to arcpy, and I am trying the simple operation of creating a dictionary that will pair my fcs in a gdb with their corresponding coordinate system. 
The operation itself works, but it only returns ONE (random) entry in my dictionary, instead of all fcs in the gdb, and I can't figure out why.

My code reads as follows:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
# define source of data
arcpy.env.workspace = "R:/02_Vektor/ALKIS.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
# list fcs  
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
# create a dictionary that couples shapes with their respective COS
for fc in fcs:
    COS = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference.name
    MK_dict = {
        fc : COS
        }
# check output
print MK_dict
```

Comment: `overWriteOutput = True` means that output that already exists will be silently overwritten

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which stresses the importance of asking one question per question. This is a basic Python issue, which isn't really GIS-centric (hint: you need to learn how to create a dictionary and populate dictionary entries).

Comment: Please only ask one question per question. Your second has been removed - it has already been answered using a comment anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that each time around the loop you create a new dictionary called `MK_dict` over writing the previous one.

```
MK_dict = {}
for fc in fcs:
    COS = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference.name
    MK_dict[fc]= COS
```

is probably what you want.

Comment: Ideally, I want the dictionary to work the other way around, i.e. the key to be the coordinate system and the corresponding value to be the fc.
The problem is, that if I put
       MK_dict[fc]= COS
then it will only give as many entries as I have different spatial references. How can I fill the dictionary with all my data?

Comment: then you can switch the variables around, but you may need a dict of lists to allow for more than one dataset having the same CRS